# Python _Pandas/Drop table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new in python. I need remove the rows which was available in dt2 from dt1.

example

dt1

```
Client  Acct#   Last Note   Last Message
XXY  F1000  completed      Payer
XXY  F1001  not completed  Payer
XXY  F1002                 Payer
XXY  F1003  complete      Payer end
XXY F1004                Payer end
XXY F1005   moved        value
XXY F1006                value
XXY F1007   moved       payer
```

dt2

```
Client  Acct#   Last Note   Last Message
XXY    F1002               Payer
XXY    F1004               Payer end
```

result

```
Client  Acct#   Last Note   Last Message
XXY F1000   completed       Payer
XXY F1001   not completed   Payer
XXY F1003   complete        Payer end
XXY F1005   moved          value
XXY F1006                  value
XXY F1007   moved          payer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge` with indicator and use it for boolean indexing:

```
(df1
 .merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
 .loc[lambda d: d.pop('_merge').ne('right_only')]
)
```